# Dropbox Sync API for C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dropbox, dropbox-api

I understand that there are iOS and Android libraries where there's no problem to use [Dropbox Sync APIs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync). I also have an application developed for Windows desktop using Visual Studio 2008 and C++/MFC (or Win APIs).

Is there any tutorial how to implement that Dropbox Sync via plain https? (JSON or REST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underneath, everything is just a web API, so check out the Core API HTTP docs and go from there: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs.

Comment: OK, bear with me. I was just browsing through that page too and even though uploading or downloading files seems to be pretty straightforward, but I couldn't find a single reference to implementing the sync itself. For instance, using the Dropbox terminology, how do I add "observer" to the file being sync'ed? Or in other words, how do I get notified that my file was changed at the Dropbox server?

Comment: "Observer" sounds like iOS terminology to me. :-) You want https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#longpoll-delta for long-polling and https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta to get the actual changes (since last call).

Comment: Good catch. Thank you. That sounds like what I need. So basically it's all based on my app "polling" the server for changes, right?

Comment: Right. These are exactly the same endpoints that the Sync API uses to monitor for changes.